# I need to construct a matrix of the following form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let a matrix $\theta = $

$  \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 &\cdots \cdots \cdots & 1\\
        \theta_{11} & \theta_{12} &\cdots & \theta_{1n} \\
       \theta_{21} & \theta_{22} &\cdots & \theta_{2n}  \\
\theta_{31} & \theta_{32} &\cdots & \theta_{3n} \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots& \vdots\\
\theta_{n-1,1} & \theta_{n-1,2} &\cdots & \theta_{n-1,n}  
 \end{bmatrix}
$

such that

- $ \theta_{i1}+\theta_{i2} +\cdots  +\theta_{in} = 1,$
- matrix $\theta$ is invertible,
- And all the entries of the matrix are non zero and non negative.

$\theta$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.

For a given $n$, I need an algorithm to follow to get a matrix of the above form.

Comment: Urgency will get you nowhere here.  We are not a free service site to do your homework, pay up by showing us what you've tried.

Comment: You moved the goal of the problem, but this gives you another chance to show some work.  **Hint:** The solution offered in the first two Answers can be modified very slightly to solve your revised Question.

Comment: okay @hardmath that's a helpful hint. maybe (!!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the matrix:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0\\   
 \end{bmatrix}$$

which is a so-called "companion matrix" with determinant $(-1)^n \neq 0$ and characteristic polynomial :

$x^{n}-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}- \cdots - x -1$

**Edit: new answer with your new constraint** about strict positivity of the entries:

For the case $n=4$, take

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        1       &       1      &        1       &       1     \\  
       2/5       &     1/5     &       1/5      &      1/5     \\
       1/5       &     2/5     &       1/5      &      1/5     \\
       1/5      &      1/5     &       2/5      &      1/5 
 \end{bmatrix}$$

For the case $n=5$, take:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        1       &       1     &         1    &          1    &   1 \\
       2/6      &      1/6    &       1/6   &         1/6   &   1/6\\
       1/6      &      2/6    &        1/6  &          1/6   &   1/6\\
       1/6      &      1/6    &        2/6  &          1/6   &  1/6\\ 
       1/6      &      1/6    &        1/6  &          2/6   &  1/6
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Do you see the general pattern ? (It is rather similar to the first proposition with the companion matrix).

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But i forgot to mention. The entries will have to be non zero also. I have updated it. can you now tell me how to proceed ?

Comment: I have a proposal for the case where all entries must be $>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Moreover the determinants are "nice", in the general case, it is $((-1)/(n+1))^{n-1} \neq 0$

Comment: Yes . It was a very good solution. thank you. Tomorrow's my project submission. I was stuck here. Thank you. :)

Comment: Next time, think to show your attempts at solving the problem. This is the way this site works...

Comment: i understand that. but this problem doesnt at all fall in my domain. and i was stuck in the beginning. couldn't even start.

Comment: Yes, I understand that also, it happens. One thing that has helped me is to transform the condition "sum of lines = 1" into the product of matrix $\theta$ by the vector $\mathbb{1}$ (with entries all equal to 1) is the vector with coefficients $n,1,1, \cdots 1$...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 &\cdots & 0 & 0  \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots&  \vdots & \vdots\\
0& 0 &\cdots & 1 & 0  
 \end{bmatrix}
this matrix is invertible and all the entries are non negative.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But i forgot to mention. The entries will have to be non zero also. I have updated it. 

can you now tell me how to proceed ?

Comment: I see we have had the same idea independently

Comment: No entries should be 0? @saudade

Comment: No .Actually I need the matrix for my project. And in that context entries can't be zero.